# alpha border inside image

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a border inside an image instead of outside of the image.  I want to do this because I would like to put some alpha value on the border so that i can see the image through the border.

I tried placing a div a few pixels smaller than the image around the image and then setting "overflow:none".  The border is now inside the image, but when i apply alpha to the border nothing can be seen through the border because overflow is set to none.

On the other hand.  If i don't set "overflow", then the border won't show up.

I want something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested in firefox and ie8 (no opacity yet in ie8, but you can use a filter for that):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
           "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .imgcontainer{padding:0; position: relative; 
                        display: inline-block; overflow: hidden;}
            .imgcontainer img{display:block;}
            .borders, .borders2{position: absolute; width:100%; height:100%;
                        border: 4px solid #000;}
            .borders{opacity: .5;}
            .borders2{bottom: 4px; right: 4px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="imgcontainer">
            <div class="borders"><div class="borders2"></div></div>
            <img src="img" />
        </div>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

This creates a 4px transparent border, but that can easily be changed. 
Because the opacity only affects the absolute positioned divs the image doesnot become transparent. Two border-divs are needed in this example because this way the image size is variable, if your images always have the same size you could do this with only one.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xb37w/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper with negative margins and rgba(255,255,255,.5) as border-color.

Comment: Negative margins don't work like this (at least in firefox), the border still displays around the image, margin always renders outside the border. Also rgba as border-color isn't supported by internet explorer, so you might want to use another method for creating the transparency.

Comment: IE don't support any type of transparency except pngs-24 but in this case you have to use border-image... which is not implemented in IE. The best approch would be to create "pre-borderer" images yourself or with PHP library such GD.

Comment: IE does do transparency, just add this css style: filter:alpha(opacity=50); or filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50); 
IE only and remember that this affects the whole element and all contents, so don't apply this to the image, only to the borders.